# Can I wire a Pump Start Relay to an outdoor GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor, pump, relay

I have an existing outdoor GFCI outlet. Can I wire a pump relay to the existing outlet, and put another GFCI outlet after the relay? The goal is to have the second outlet only powered when the relay is "switched on."

**Background**:
I've got a tank that is collecting rainwater. I'm wanting to use that water to feed some raised beds using an opensprinkler pi (OSpi). I want to use the OSpi to activate a pump start relay, which would then give power to the outlet and turn the pump on (pump is activated when hit with power, no on/off switch). I already have a pump that has a three-prong plug, and I'd like to keep that intact if possible, hence to wiring the outlet.

**Setup**:
-Dedicated circuit on a 20A breaker
-Existing outdoor GFCI outlet on the previously mentioned circuit
-All outlets are/will be housed in weather resistant bubble enclosures ([like this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TayMac-1-Gang-Rectangle-Plastic-Weatherproof-Electrical-Box-Cover/50372928))
-Pump Start relay comes with/will be housed in [weatherproof enclosure](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Orbit-Gray-Silver-Pump-Start-Relay/3424932)
-Pump and sprinkler valves will also be in weatherproof housings/covered

**Proposed Design/Wiring Diagram**
[image: pump start relay outlet design image]
Link to the above image can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk9Wf.png

Comment: Have you bought the AFCI breaker yet?

Comment: There's no need for an additional GFCI after the relay. The GFCI feeding it will catch any ground fault.

Comment: @Harper Yes, and sorry, I botched the name. The [CAFI breaker](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Square-D-Homeline-20-Amp-1-Pole-Combination-Arc-Fault-Circuit-Breaker/50311127) has already been purchased and is installed. For clarity, everything up to and including the first GFCI outlet is already installed.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, excellent thanks. Other than chasing down which outlet might be tripping, is there any downside/negative if that second outlet is also GFCI?

Comment: Yes. Your arrangement will have you severing power to the GFCI's inputs.  Many GFCIs do not like that and will have weird trip problems.  You might find one that is ok, but GFCIs don't live long outdoors, and you'll be changing it periodically and you'll have to hunt down a power-sever-tolerant GFCI everytime.  Also it means that some other circuit in your house isn't protected at all because you wasted a GFCI.  It is a complete and total waste to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is why GFCIs have LOAD terminals

A receptacle-type GFCI has two sets of terminals: LINE and LOAD.  The use of the LINE terminals is simple -- these are where power is applied to the GFCI.  The LOAD terminals, though, are interesting -- they are effectively a third receptacle on the back of the GFCI, only implemented using screw terminals or backstabs instead of normal NEMA receptacle contacts.  In other words, they *extend* GFCI protection to whatever is connected to them.

So, you can connect the wires feeding power to your pump start relay box (hot + neutral) to the LOAD terminals on the existing GFCI.  This way, you don't need to put in another GFCI, just a standard receptacle, and you don't have to worry about oddities that might be caused by the second GFCI having power cut to it on a regular basis.  Just remember to put one of those "GFCI PROTECTED" stickers on the regular outlet that you're wiring up to the pump start box if you do this!

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll go with your suggestion above, use a standard receptacle, and be sure to label with a "GFCI Protected" sticker. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will work to use the contacts of the relay to switch the pump power, tapped from the load side terminals of the existing GFCI to run the pump receptacle.

I personally might use a single (not duplex) non-GFCI receptacle for the pump.  If you use a duplex receptacle it seems like someone will eventually unintentionally plug something in there expecting constant power.

If you don't want to risk whatever gets plugged into that GFCI receptacle overloading the pump circuit - make it really dedicated - you could even use a dead front GFCI there instead of a receptacle.

Comment: Great idea, I think I'll go with the single non-GFCI receptacle for the pump so there's no confusion on that side.